# Apache rewrite rule works for homepage but not links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, kirby

I have a site in a `/www/` folder. In the parent directory I have an .htaccess file which passes through the `/www/` directory so it is as if it does not exist.

Within that folder I have Kirby CMS as a submodule which uses it's own rewrite rules for urls.  The homepage shows as `http://mywebsite.local` but the links are shown as `http://mywebsite.local/www/page-name`. They are dynamically generated in PHP and not hard coded.

**Manually removing the `/www/` from the url shows that the redirect works fine.** So it must be a Kirby issue.

`kirbycms` is a git submodule and I have followed this tutorial http://rimann.org/blog/kirby-git-setup.

Structure:

```
|- .htaccess
|- www
|- |- index.php
|- |- .htaccess
|- |- kirbycms
|- |- |- kirby
|- |- themes
|- |- |- v9
|- |- |- |- site
```

root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond $1 !^www/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

kirby .htaccess:

```
# Kirby .htaccess

# rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# enable awesome urls. i.e.:
# http://yourdomain.com/about-us/team
RewriteEngine on

# make sure to set the RewriteBase correctly
# if you are running the site in a subfolder.
# Otherwise links or the entire site will break.
#
# If your homepage is http://yourdomain.com/mysite
# Set the RewriteBase to:
#
# RewriteBase /mysite
#
RewriteBase /

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the kirby folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# leave robots.txt alone for search engines
RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots.txt [L]

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>


# Additional recommended values
# Remove comments for those you want to use.
#
# AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#
# php_flag short_open_tag on
```

index.php:

```
<?php

/*

---------------------------------------
Document root of your site
---------------------------------------
this should be identical with the directory
in which your index.php is located

*/

$root = dirname(__FILE__);



/*

---------------------------------------
Kirby system folder
---------------------------------------

by default this is located inside the root directory
but if you want to share one system folder for
multiple sites, you can easily change that here
and link to a shared kirby folder somewhere on your
server

*/

$rootKirby = $root . '/kirbycms/kirby';



/*

---------------------------------------
Your site folder
---------------------------------------

Your site folder contains all the site specific files
like templates and snippets. It is located in the root
directory by default, but you can move it if you want.

*/

$rootSite = $root . '/theme/v9/site';



/*

---------------------------------------
Your content folder
---------------------------------------

Your content folder is also located in the root
directory by default. You can change this here.
It can also be changed later in your site/config.php

*/

$rootContent = $root . '/content';


// Try to load Kirby
if(!file_exists($rootKirby . '/system.php')) {
  die('The Kirby system could not be loaded');
}

require_once($rootKirby . '/system.php');
```

Does anyone know how I can set the links so they don't have the `/www/`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. It was a Kirby config option to have the site in a subfolder.

in `site/config/config.php` there is an option for `c::set('subfolder', false);` which needs to be set to true.

Then the `www` goes away.